# public class field react being used to bind callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {counter: 0}

  constructor() {
    super()

    // Like homework or situps; something you have to do :(
    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this) 
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    this.setState(ps => {
      return {counter: ps.counter + 1}
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
        </p>
        <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

how is the above code different from

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {counter: 0}

  incrementCounter = () => {
    this.setState(ps => {
      return {counter: ps.counter + 1}
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
        </p>
        <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

it's mentioned that incrementCounter is using public class field in the second case. But apart from incrementCounter function being converted to arrow function, i don't see a difference. Does using arrow function when used to define any class method makes it public class field. In the second case how is `this` inside the incrementCounter function pointing to the App component when it is being used directly with `button onClick` handler.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the arrow function takes the value of `this` from its surrounding scope, which in your case is the class instance. Unlike in your first example where the `this` inside of the `incrementCounter` is determined by how the `incrementCounter()` method was executed. Your second example is the same as writing:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {counter: 0}
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.incrementCounter = () => {
      this.setState(ps => { // `this` comes from the binding associated. with the `constructor()`
        return {counter: ps.counter + 1}
      })
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
        </p>
        <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `this` inside of the `incrementCounter` arrow function will always refer back to the `this` from the constructor's scope (which is your instance), and doesn't get influenced by how it was invoked. However,  in your first example using the class method, your `this` *is* determined by how it's invoked, and so you need to bind it beforehand to specify its value.